# HTML Canvas Won't Draw Line

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have the following code to draw a line, but it won't draw. I only see the canvas border.  I don't see any errors in the console.

index.html:

```
<div id="chart_area">
     <canvas id="chart1" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
</div>
...
<script>
     processChart()
</script>
```

style.css:

```
#chart_area
 {
 text-align:center;
 color:red;

 } 

 #chart1
 {
 text-align:center;
 border:solid;
 color:blue;

 } 

#control_panel
 {
 text-align:center;
 color:red;
 float:right;
 clear:both;
 }
```

chart.js:

```
function processChart() {
        var b_canvas = document.getElementById("chart1");
        var b_context = b_canvas.getContext("2d");
            b_context.moveTo([0,0]);
            b_context.lineTo([300,300]);
            b_context.stroke()  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Those functions take two arguments, not an array. Also be sure to call beginPath prior to drawing paths, you'll get confused later if you dont :) Your code should be

```
b_context.beginPath();
b_context.moveTo(0, 0);
b_context.lineTo(300, 300);
b_context.stroke()
```

Some canvas tutorials:

- [MDN](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial) is always good.
- [This one](http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-canvas-path.php) from html5tutorial.info looks good and is focused on path drawing.

Comment: Both links are broken. try [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D)

Answer (score 1):

You should remove your '['
try this:

```
b_canvas = document.getElementById("chart1");
        var b_context = b_canvas.getContext("2d");
            b_context.moveTo(11,0);
            b_context.lineTo(200,300);
            b_context.stroke();
```

Comment: You forgot to beginPath. Doing so consistently will cause problems when you try to draw additional paths.

Comment: @JacobParker You are right. But I just corrected it to work. like this: http://jsfiddle.net/VZmq4/

Comment: Yeah, that works for one line, but rarely do we only want to draw one line :)

Comment: Yep, I'm not gonna argue with you.